# What ways (beyond spells) is "concussive" (thunder) damage able to be obtained?

Tags: dnd-5e, damage-types

I know that there are various spells that have thunder [concussive] damage listed, but are there any other ways of getting this damage type?

- Equipment?
- Class features or entire classes?
- Monsters who have it naturally?

All books are on the table for this question.

Sometimes Sonic attacks are called thunder as per [this question,](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/30849/would-a-concussive-bomb-deal-sonic-damage-or-something-else) which seems to list a "concussive bomb."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matt Vincent's answer covers some items and monsters, so I won't cover them here.

Clerics choosing the Tempest domain (PHB p.62) are granted two relevant abilities:

**Wrath of the Storm**, bestowed at 1st level:

> When a creature within 5 feet of you that you can see
>   hits you with an attack, you can use your reaction to
>   cause the creature to make a Dexterity saving throw.
>   The creature takes 2d8 lightning or thunder damage
>   (your choice) on a failed saving throw, and half as much
>   damage on a successful one.

**Divine Strike**, bestowed at 8th level:

> Once on each of your turns
>   when you hit a creature with a weapon attack, you can
>   cause the attack to deal an extra 1d8 thunder damage to
>   the target. When you reach 14th level, the extra damage
>   increases to 2d8.

Though these are magical effects, they explicitly aren't spells. This is in contrast to, say, the Monk's Monastic Tradition **Way of the Four Elements** (PHB p.80-81), which allows a Monk to cast spells, including *thunderwave*.

Answer (score 6):

Here are some:

[Items](http://5e.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/magicItemsAToZ.htm):

- Hammer of Thunderbolts
- Horn of Blasting
- Staff of Thunder and Lightning

Creatures:

- [Androsphinx](http://5e.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/sphinx.htm)
- [Djinni](http://5e.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/genies.htm)